# Systemd timer for unattended upgrades

Tags: systemd

I try to configure unattended upgrades with systemd timer as explained [here](https://wiki.debian.org/UnattendedUpgrades#Modifying_download_and_upgrade_schedules_.28on_systemd.29)

I configured `/etc/systemd/system/apt-daily-upgrade.timer.d/override.conf` file like that :

```
[Unit]
Description=Daily apt upgrade and clean activities
After=apt-daily.timer

[Timer]
OnCalendar=Mon,Wed,Fri 6:00
RandomizedDelaySec=60m
Persistent=true

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

When I check when will be next trigger I get :

```
# systemctl status apt-daily-upgrade.timer
● apt-daily-upgrade.timer - Daily apt upgrade and clean activities
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apt-daily-upgrade.timer; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/apt-daily-upgrade.timer.d
           └─override.conf
   Active: active (waiting) since Wed 2020-03-11 13:23:17 UTC; 53min ago
  Trigger: Thu 2020-03-12 06:31:32 UTC; 16h left
```

So it supposes to be triggered next thursday while Thus is not definied in OnCalendar parameter.

Don't see what I miss :/

Thanks

Comment: and why don't you just use cron ?

Answer (score 0):

found, timers are cumulative, so existing timers should be reset :

```
[Timer]
OnCalendar=
OnCalendar=Mon,Wed,Fri 6:00
```

It now works fine.